# What is the advantage of using Maven for creating RESTful Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, web

I am just a beginner in creating RESTful Web Services. I saw many places they are creating Maven project in Netbeans IDE for creating RESTful Web Services in JAVA EE.

Can someone help me with this that what are advantages of using MAVEN?

How it is helpful, I have little to no knowledge of Maven I searched it over Internet but don't get exact Idea.

Comment: Just Google ***[MAVEN](https://maven.apache.org/)*** and boom you have your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is automation tool that is designed for java projects.It will provide the structure for the java project you are building and will take care of jars.

It creates a repository where it store all the jar that were downloaded automatically by your java program.If you want to see your repository you can go through the path like

```
C:\Users\UserName\.m2
```

If talking about Restful there is no relation with maven it will only provide you pom.xml file where you can write all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Maven itself does not have anything to do with RESTful services. It's a build management tool helping to create projects and managing dependencies.

[Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)